# Apache settings for SPA using HTML5 History routing

Tags: apache, single-page-application, html5-history

My team recently updated our legacy SPAs routing implementation from hash-based to HTML5 History routing. Now we need to update our Apache settings to allow “clean URLs” to be handled by the SPA. This is easy enough with the `FallbackResource` directive:

`FallbackResource /index.html`

This loads the SPA for all file and directory requests that don’t actually map to a file/directory on disk.

However, I would still like files that don’t actually exist load our servers 404.html page and respond with 404 status, instead of “falling back” to the SPAs index.html.

How could I configure Apache to only fall back to the index.html page for directories that don’t exist (`/some/route`), but for file requests (`/somefile.css`) that don’t exist render a 404 status and page?

I’ve tried various `RewriteCond/RewriteRule` combinations with no luck.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to be able to provide one kind of response for directories, or paths that look like directories (e.g. `/financing/terms`), and a different kind of response for files, then I believe the [Files directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#files) is what you're looking for.

I created a [branch in a GitHub repo](https://github.com/headquarters/apache-redirects-test/tree/fallbackresource) that has a Docker image with Apache and a sample single page app from Ember to demonstrate the solution. To test it out, clone the repo and checkout the `fallbackresource` branch. From there, assuming you have Docker installed, follow the directions in the README. The server will start on port 80 so then you can visit `http://localhost`. A screenshot of the SPA running is below.

[image: localhost/rentals shown in Chrome]

Localhost redirects to http://localhost/rentals once the single page app kicks in and redirects. Notice the 404 in the network tab--there is a link to a non-existent JS file that is throwing a 404 instead of falling back to the index.html file.

This works due to the Files directive in the configuration file (viewable below and in [the source for that branch](https://github.com/headquarters/apache-redirects-test/blob/fallbackresource/httpd.conf#L503-L512)).

```
# Map all SPA-looking routes to our single page app index file
<Directory ~ "^/[\w+\d+-]+">
  FallbackResource /index.html
</Directory>

# Requests for files should return a real 404 and not fallback to the index.html page, though
<Files ~ "\.(js|css|gif|jpe?g|png)$">
  FallbackResource disabled
  ErrorDocument 404 "File not found"
</Files>
```

The `Directory` directive uses a regular expression to match to word characters, digits, and hyphens so that routes you probably want mapped to SPA routes should fallback to the index.html file. However, individual file type requests do not fallback because the `Files` directive disables the FallbackResource property.

Combining these two directives in your Apache config should give you the behavior you're shooting for.